# Element Broadcasting issue due to shape mismatch

Tags: python, matlab, networking

I have just converted the MATLAB code into Python, where the error occurred in the following Notebook statement:

```
Pfa = np.sum(np.logical_and(Ted > Thres, TX == 0)) / nH0
```

**ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5000,) (50,)**

The difference is that in MATLAB, it was able to store the values for `Pfa` and plot the `ROC` Curve such as the following image:

[image: ROC Curve]

But does not, in the case of Python.

Can anyone please help me out with this minor issue?

Comment: The error indicates that the your matrices are not in valid shapes for the operation. Have you printed the shapes of your variables already?

Comment: Yes, I have.

The shapes of the following variables are as follows:

Ted=(5000,)
Thres=(50,)
TX=(5000,).

In the case of MATLAB, broadcasting of elements seems to be fine, but an error occurs in Python where I need to reshape one of the arrays.

Comment: Then explicitly broadcast (i.e. repmat `Thres`). Easy fix.

Comment: The graph plot shows only a dot. Since the variables Pfa and Pd stores only one value. But in the case of MATLAB, Pfa and Pd stores the results as a list of values, as in [1x5000].

Comment: @AnderBiguri There seems to be some issue with the Python code when it is converted from MATLAB. The "sum" function in Python, doesn't work the same way as compared to the MATLAB's "sum" function.

Comment: @XCPT1ON  I think your issue is with the `np.logical_and()` What are the lengths of `Ted > Thres` and  `TX == 0`? The documentation states that they must be the same shape

Comment: @user22034139 The ```np.logical_and()``` function had to be used, since there was an issue using the "&" function. The sizes of ```Ted, Thres and TX``` are [5000,1], [1,50] and [5000,1], since this was converted from MATLAB to Python.

Comment: Two functions not working the same in two different languages should be your expected behaviour, not a rarity. Read the documentation for both.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Understood. Read the documentation, and found what the issue was. Although, another issue is with the graph output, since only one point was plotted using this statement: ```Pfa = np.sum((Ted_new > Thres) & (TX_new == 0)) / nH0```. Is there any work around for the points to be plotted (such as using for loops and appending the resultant array ```Pfa```)?